# How to effectively manage array element using Vuex?

Tags: javascript, vuex

I started using Vuex in a new project and I really like it.
But the thing I still do not understand is how am I supposed to efficiently manage a state of array elements?

Take a look at the example.
Suppose I open the page and the following response gets loaded from the backend:

```
{
  "reportName": "Parent name",
  "groups": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "child group name 1",
      "elements": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "name": "sub-child el 1",
          "enabled": false
        },
        ...
      ]
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

The entity has an array of child entities. And each child element has a sub-child.

Now suppose that I have a dedicated component to display each level: the parent entity, every child (group) and sub-child element.
There is a checkbox in sub-child component which is bound to `enabled` field.

With Vuex, I should not make changes in the state directly.
So when I press checkbox, Vue edits the state using **mutation**
and here I see 2 problems:

- To commit the mutation of sub-child element I need to know the group id (child element id) in a sub-child component.
  It forces me to pass group id as a parameter to a sub-child component which increases coupling of components.
- Also when I mutate the state, I need to scan two arrays by ids
  (first find a child (group) and then find sub-child element)

I think I am missing something and I could modify the state in a more efficient way.
And also it is probably not necessary for sub-child to know which group it belongs to.

I have a couple of thoughts on what I could do:

- Do I need to turn my arrays into objects after fetching from backend for faster access by id?
- Do I need to somehow register a submodule for each array element?

I would like you to let me know what I am doing wrong and point me to
the right direction to efficiently use Vuex to manage arrays state

Comment: You might want to read this: https://github.com/paularmstrong/normalizr. Data normalization is a good way for maintaining array-like data, not just for Redux but for all state management libraries.

Comment: @blaz looks like normalizr is the thing I need. But if I also have an access to backend code, is it better idea to normalize the JSON on backend side?

Comment: To me, nested JSON is more human-readable and easier for visually check and debug compared to normalized data. And adding some schema files and flattening data on frontend does not cost much - just a few Kb more I believe

Comment: @blaz could you please write an answer with a suggestion to normalize data and use `normalizr`? The question is unanswered, but your comments were an actual solution to my problem

Comment: Thanks. Added my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution to simplify your mutation logic is normalizing your response data. This is an example of using package [normalizr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/normalizr) to achieve that:

```
import { normalize, schema } from "normalizr";
const elementEntity = new schema.Entity('elements');
const groupEntity = new schema.Entity('groups', {
  elements: [elementEntity]
});
const reportEntity = new schema.Entity('reports', {
  groups: [groupEntity]
});
const normalizeFunc = (reportData) => normalize(reportData, reportEntity);
```

function `normalizeFunc` can be called before saving your data, as show in this Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-k6y51

By normalizing the above way, it helps to:

- Reduce time to search for particular item with given id, from O(N) with `Array.prototype.find` to O(1).
- Better logic to search parental item and child item.
- Simplify the mutation logic, at the cost of more logic for item deletion and relationship update.
- Improve Vue rendering performance, since flattened data helps to avoid unnecessary re-render if data in children or parent is updated.

Answer (score 0):

What you are questioning about it's all about architecture preferences.

Your solution can work and it's not awful.

I do not recommend you to apply your thoughts it will bring you more problem and complexity that what you have now. Passing some props and scanning an array is not that much expensive.

Nevertheless, a solution for this kind of problem is to transform all the child component in stateless mode.

What this means is pretty simple:

- Only your first parents can edit the state
- Instead of access to the state in your child components, you send them directly the value as props
- When a child component when to edit a field, instead of mutating the state directly, send an event that goes up until the first parent that
  catch the event and edit the part concerned (a possibility with some id
  or index sent by child components)

You can try this way but that mean passing all your data in your components and losing the vuex cache and improvements... Its all a matter of code preference.